# How can I screenshot full page with chrome extension in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, screenshot, headless

```
def scroll_to_bottom(driver):
    prev_height = driver.execute_script("return window.scrollY")
    while True:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 500);")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        new_height = driver.execute_script("return window.scrollY")
        if new_height == prev_height:
            break
        prev_height = new_height


chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
script_path = os.path.abspath(__file__)
naver_pass_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(script_path))),'screenshot', 'jojlddfolpiejckahpinefdikdogenjg.crx')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless') 
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-popup-blocking')
chrome_options.add_argument('--load-extension=C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Profile/Extensions/jojlddfolpiejckahpinefdikdogenjg/1.6.0_0')
chrome_service = ChromeService()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_service, options=chrome_options)

url = 'https://m.cafe.naver.com/musiclord/1087911'#sys.argv[1]
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
scroll_to_bottom(driver)
width = driver.execute_script("return Math.max( document.body.scrollWidth, document.body.offsetWidth, document.documentElement.clientWidth, document.documentElement.scrollWidth, document.documentElement.offsetWidth );")
height = driver.execute_script("return Math.max( document.body.scrollHeight, document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight );")
driver.set_window_size(width, height)
screenshot_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(script_path))),'screenshot', 'take_picture', 'resource', 'screenshot.png')
driver.save_screenshot(screenshot_file)

driver.quit()
```

I want to screenshot of full page. and I need to apply the extension...
But, If I headless true for full page, The extension is not apllied,
And, When I headless false for the extension, full page is not worked..
how can I do..? (headless=new is not worked)

I already tried the '--headless=new' then extension is work but full page is not worked
And I already tried the '--headless=chrome'... extension is not worked..
`Message: unknown error: failed to wait for extension background page to load`

And I already do the scroll down!

Comment: I suggest using a different library for this https://playwright.dev/python/docs/screenshots

Answer (score 0):

You could maximize the page when starting the webdriver

```
options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
```

Comment: I want to expand the window larger than my physical display.. 
I already tried --start-maximized.. but max is my display..
So... I think I should maximize in the headless.. (I tried virtual display but that is too hard and complex)